# How to pass a parameter in an Inertia lazy load request?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

On the inital page load I am loading specific products, however I want to partially load in missing products based on a foreign key.

For this to work I was thinking about returning two props from my controller in Laravel.
Those two props are 'products' and the lazy loading 'loadedProducts'. 'loadedProducts' will load in the products based on the property id.

Here you can see the return of my controller.

```
return Inertia::render('User/ManageMachine', [
        'products' => $products,
        'loadedProducts' => Inertia::lazy(fn ($propertyId) =>
        StorageProperty::find($propertyId)->products()->toArray()),
    ]);
```

On my front end I am trying to retrieve the 'loadedProducts' like this:

```
<script setup>
import { router, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
const fetchProducts = (propertyId) => {
router.reload( { 
        only: [ loadedProducts],
            });
</script>
```

I haven't added the propertyId in the fetchProducts function, because I have tried a lot and I wouldn't know where.

**My question for the front-end:**
How can I pass the propertyId?

**My question for the back-end:**
How can I receive the propertyId properly to use it in the lazy loading?

**Maybe the most useful question:**
Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Comment: Have you read about Inertia's Partial Reloads? https://inertiajs.com/partial-reloads

Comment: Yes I did, but I am not able to find an example of passing a parameter, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing properties to pages using Inertia is not made to do this. What you are trying to do would be best solved using an xhr request. This would allow you to add the parameter to the request, which can in turn use it to return whatever it is that you want to do in the backend.

Add an API endpoint to handle the request and call it in your Vue component using something like Axios.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure I still would have wasted another night on it. I am trying to avoid making API routes, so I opted for lazy loading the remaining products and merging them in Vue instead;

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible

```
const fetchProducts = (propertyId) => {
    router.visit( { 
            only: [ loadedProducts],
            data: {'propertyId': propertyId},
            preserveScroll: true,
            preserveState: true,
            onSuccess: (page) => {
                //resolve
            },
                });
```